# How can I pass the value of picker to select my Entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I am just learning core data by creating an expenses tracker app.  I have 2 Entities , Category and Transaction.  Category can hold many transactions and the model is created correctly.

I have a picker selecting the category for my AddTransactionViewController. I use the following code to save my transaction when the Save button is pressed

```
 _savedTransaction.type = [_pickerCategories objectAtIndex:[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
 _savedTransaction.timestamp = [NSDate date];
 _savedTransaction.amount = transactionAmount.text
 _savedTransaction.category = _transactionCategory;
```

I am sure I am doing something stupid with my Save because the `_savedTransaction.category`is returning `null` when I Log it. The other parameters Log correctly, so the transaction is saved... 
How can i store the transactionCategory from the value set by the picker?

Comment: What is `_transactionCategory`?

Comment: _transactionCategory is a property of type Category (my entity class)

Comment: This is what I'm asking. Is it a int, double, float, varchar. What type it is?

Comment: it is NSManaged Object subclass, which has 2 attributes: name and displayOrder - a string and a number

Comment: OK and waht type is your `_savedTransaction.category` property?

Comment: it is of type Category as well. it is the relationship between my 2 entities

Comment: Solved! Found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217058/obtaining-values-of-an-attribute-through-relationships-using-core-data-current?rq=1

Comment: Solved! found my  answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217058/obtaining-values-of-an-attribute-through-relationships-using-core-data-current?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the value of picker view to your category

_savedTransaction.category =  [_pickerCategories objectAtIndex:[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

Comment: I tried that...I get an error that I am passing an object of type NSString to a type Category

Comment: just make the category to the string type in CoreData. I believe you are using categories in the form of strings.

Comment: category is the relationship between my 2 entities, sorry I should have been more clear

Comment: And why saving `NSManagedObject` in `CoreData`

Comment: thanks for your replies. my problem is solved. found my answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217058/obtaining-values-of-an-attribute-through-relationships-using-core-data-current?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.xcdatamodeld` file, click on your `savedTransaction` Entity and change its `category` property type to `NSString`. After you modify your `CoreData` you will have to delete the existing app from your device/simulator and run/install it again. Then simply use the following logic

```
_savedTransaction.category = [_pickerCategories objectAtIndex:[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

And should be saving your category as a string. 
You can also change your category property type to `integer 16` if you wish to save just the index of your category instead of the name as a string. In this case simply save it as

```
_savedTransaction.category = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```